# Optimizing ajax to reduce mysql server load

Tags: php, mysql

I have an auction site that sometimes becomes heavily loaded & mostly mysql is seen to consume lot of memory & cpu. The situation i have is as below.

An ajax query is going to mysql every second for every user who is online & watching the auction to check the bid count against a previous value. If anyone places a bid, the count is different, so this ajax invokes one more ajax that retrieves records & displays in a table bids that are specific to the user who is watching / logged in. I'm limiting this to first 10 to reduce load.

However the problem is if there are 50 users online, & one of them places a bid, 50 queries go into mysql & all of them detect the bid count has changed & issue further queries to get records to display bids corresponding to each user.

THe bigger problem is if there are 500 users online then 500 queries go into mysql to detect a change & if a bid is placed another 500 queries (a query specific to each online user) go into mysql & potentially crash the server.

Note: Currently there is a single mysql connection object used as a singleton in a php that is responsible for executing queries, retrieving records, etc.

I'm essentially looking at a solution where 500 queries don't goto mysql if 500 users are online, but all of them should get an update even if one of them places a bid for a particular auction. Any ideas / suggestions highly welcome.

How can i best implement a solution for this scenario that reduce the load on mysql ?

Resource wise we are fairly ok, doing a VPS4 on Hostgator. The only problem is cpu / memory usage which is 95% when many users are placing bids.

Appreciate some suggestions

Comment: If you could have a long-running process, then it could look up and cache the value every second so you don't have to go all the way back to MySQL. I have no idea how to do that in PHP though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will want to take a look at memcached or some other caching service. You can have a process querying MySQL and updating it into memcached, and ajax making a query directly into memcached to retrieve the rows.

Memcached does not keep the relational consistency, and querying it is much less resource consuming than querying MySQL every single time.

PHP has a very nice interface to work with memcached: [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)

[The website of the memcached project.](http://memcached.org/)

There are a few other caching services. You might also want to look at query caching in MySQL, but this would still need several connections into MySQL, which will be very resource consuming either way.

Comment: Hello. Doing this memcahce is very tricky because the process that queries database can do so every second, but in 1 second we expect some 50-60 bids for the auction. This implies the cached data is already out of sync, although its just by a second. So the ajax's querying memcache are likely to get either wrong / out of sync information.

Comment: Well AJAX doesn't bring completely up-to-date results either. It takes a few round trip times to the server to retrieve all the info. You could also look at lightweight connections to MySQL, or distributing the load on a couple MySQL instances.

Answer (score 0):

In the short-term, you could also just run the detailed query.  It will return nothing when there's nothing to update (which replaces the first query!).

That might buy you some time for caching or deeper analysis of your query speed.